# Avoid Jquery to hide a message with display:none

Tags: jquery, onclick, message

hope I can find a way to show two messages when click on a link, I miss a message (Product Added) cause the display:none - it seems there is no way to keep visible the second message :(

This is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.shop').click(function(){
$(this).next('.add-button .btn-bottom-linea a').text('Product Added').delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
$(this).text('Add another product').hide().delay(3500).fadeIn(500);
});
});
</script>

<a href="#0" class="shop add-button btn-bottom-line">Add Product</a>
```

Comment: so one message is coming and other is hiding ...am i correct ?

Comment: Please provide the *entire* HTML that's relevant to this question. This won't run for us, so we can't see what your talking about.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Messages</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.shop').click(function(){
$(this).next('.add-button .btn-bottom-linea a').text('Product Added').delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
$(this).text('Add another product').hide().delay(3500).fadeIn(500);
});
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<a href="#0" class="shop add-button btn-bottom-line">Add Product</a>  
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing here is that you are not waiting  to add the new text.

If you see [here](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) you can see that .fadeOut(duration, complete) accepts 2 parameters, the first is the time in miliseconds, the second is the callback that will be called after the animation.

The code should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.shop').click(function(e){

        var element = $(this);
        element.text('Product Added').delay(3000).fadeOut(500, function () {
            element.text('Add another product').hide().delay(3500).fadeIn(500);
        });
    });

});
```

Check out promises in JS and don't forget to check documentation when using a library of framework.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong... it should be element first and then the class

```
.next('.add-button .btn-bottom-linea a')
```

should actually be

```
 .next('a.add-button')   // since once class selector is enough
```

here is a working example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.shop').click(function(){
  $(this).next('a.btn-bottom-line').text('Product    Added').delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
        
  $(this).text('Add anthr product').delay(3500).fadeIn(500);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<a href="#0" class="shop add-button btn-bottom-line">Add Product</a>
 
<a href="#0" class="shop add-button btn-bottom-line">Add Product</a>
```